# Date in textboxes changing format

Tags: .net, culture, date-format

I have an application (asp.net 3.5) that support 4 different languages.  Along with other cultural changes, the date formats must match the current culture on out reporting pages.

We set the date formats of each of the textboxes like:

```
string date = DateTime.Today.ToString("d"); //returns the date portion only

textbox1.Text = date;
textbox2.Text = date;

etc...
```

When the user selects Spanish or British English the format should be dd/mm/yyyy. However, then I navigate to the page it displays in mm/dd/yyyy.  After a postback it then displays dd/mm/yyyy.  After another postback it switches to the mm/dd/yyyy format and on and on.

I have debugged through this and I see that the culture is correct for the application and the date formats are returned to me correctly, yet when it displays, it displays incorrectly.

Has anyone ever seen this or know what is happening?

Comment: You've quoted "dd/mm/yyyy" format 4 times, claiming it's switching... could you check the exact details? It's hard to diagnose a problem without the facts :)

Comment: I think you meant to type mm/dd/yyyy a few times in there instead.

Comment: Sorry...Dont know how I did that.  It should be better now.  Got a tad ahead of myself...

Comment: Where are you assigning the culture setting, and remember to set the uiculture as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing culture for just one page you should override `InitializeCulture` for the aspx pages in questions:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    // set your culture, or pick it from maybe the Request object
    string selectedLanguage = "en-US"; 
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);
    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

If you want to set culture for the whole app, use `Application_BeginRequest` in global.asax.

```
void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string selectedLanguage = "en-US"; 
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);
}
```

You would of course change en-US to the correct culture for your users.